# Using GDAL's Rasterize (Vector to Raster) utility?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to convert a point layer to a raster file using QGIS python consle. I want the output raster with the extent of a raster file. The new raster should have the point values from the specified field of the input vector and a value of 0 elsewhere.

I am using GDAL's Rasterize (Vector to Raster) utility (https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/rasterize.html). 
This documentation is for QGIS 2.8 version while I am running my script QGIS v. 3.6.3 and 3.4.8.

I am getting error:

```
'Incorrect parameter value for UNITS' for the last line of the code, that is for the output.
```

I have seen several existing posts on QGIS but I still couldn't solve this issue. Like for instance, when I use the script given here: [Rasterizing shapefiles with GDAL and Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212795/rasterizing-shapefiles-with-gdal-and-python) I get an output raster with a 0 value for all pixels.

I also tried by giving the pixel size instead of extent by following this post - [extent parameter pyqgis gdal processing rasterize](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227802/extent-parameter-pyqgis-gdal-processing-rasterize). But then too I get the same error of 'Incorrect parameter value for UNITS'.

Using the code given in another post [Python, creating layers and rasterizing polygons in GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262240/python-creating-layers-and-rasterizing-polygons-in-gdal)
I get the error:

```
'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetGeoTransform'.
```

I checked documentation for SetGeoTransform and I failed to figure out what went missing. With different codes I am getting different error.

I am attaching the code that I have used.

I just do not seem to understand why the 'Units' error is occurring. Both input data have same projection.

```
import os 
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
import processing
#input = iface.activeLayer()
input = 'C:\Trials\points.shp'
#layer = QgsVectorLayer(input.source(),"point","ogr")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(input,"point", "ogr")

#Raster extent for the new layer
St_Area_Rst = 'C:\Trials\Extent.tif'
#collecting dimensions of the above raster
dim = gdal.Open(St_Area_Rst)
xoff,a,b,yoff,c,d = dim.GetGeoTransform()
band1= dim.GetRasterBand(1)
rows = dim.RasterYSize
cols = dim.RasterXSize
Total_pixel = (rows*cols)
#specifying extent of input layer
extent = layer.extent()
xmin = xoff
xmax = xoff + (a*cols)
ymin = yoff + (d*rows)
ymax = yoff
output = 'C:\Trials\points_rst.tif'
processing.run("gdal:rasterize",
               {"INPUT":layer,
               "FIELD":"Rstrz",
               "DIMENSIONS":0,
               "WIDTH":cols,
               "HEIGHT":rows,
               "RAST_EXT":"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
               "TFW":1,
               "RTYPE":4,
               "NO_DATA":0,
               "COMPRESS":0,
               "JPEGCOMPRESSION":1,
               "ZLEVEL":1,
               "PREDICTOR":1,
               "TILED":False,
               "BIGTIFF":2,
               "EXTRA": '',
               "OUTPUT":output})
```

Comment: are you bound to gdal rasterize? try https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/features.html or http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/4.0.0/grid_gridding_0.html with https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/wiki/Executing%20Modules%20with%20SAGA%20CMD/

Comment: I had tried installing rasterio, could not do it using anaconda because the site is blocked by the network. pip installation did not work saying network connection timed out. I found gdal script very simple in understanding and if it works I would try to incorporate it in a GUI. I am still learning the basics of QGIS-python-GUI skills

Answer (score 2):

I was trying GDAL:rasterize yesterday but eventually gave up. My data was a bit fragmented for GDAL to accept it, and some other issues I couldn't solve. However, I had success using **Grass *v.to.rast*** in QGIS (3.8). It felt like a "simpler" to use tool for what I  was doing, as long as you pay attention to the settings in the "advanced" section. In my case this regarded the cell size.

This is not a solution to your problem, but may be an option to get the result you are after.